# MSSQL Searching Database tables and views

Tags: sql-server

I was given a task to write very specific queries from a microsoft sql server database that has over 250 tables and over 250 views. I am using sql server management studios and I am trying to figure out where a field location might exist in a table.

Are there ways to do a quick search of every table or the entire database for certain keywords to help narrow down my searches?

Or must I open every single table/view and try to see every single column in order to solve this issue?

Any help or advice with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for the column name or the value in a column?

Comment: `sys.tables`, `sys.views`, `sys.columns`, go nuts. You can write queries that use these views to produce other queries.

Comment: Either I am sure I will have many searches. Is it possible to search both column names and the data that is inside. For example if i wanted to find a location could I search the entire database with a wildcard of `*loc` or if i know certain locations maybe search `desoto` in the data.

Comment: Column names and the data in the tables are completely different animals. You would search sys.columns for the column name. But to search all the tables looking for a value is an entirely different thing. And it is going to be stupidly slow. It is like asking somebody to find all occurrences of "sm" in a phonebook. You are going to have to look at every single name and address on every single page.

Comment: [Searching the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+search+all+tables&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS727US727&oq=sql+server+search+all+tables&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3723j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) will usually find similar discussions and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try SQL Search from Redgate. Very powerful tool, you can download it for free:
https://www.red-gate.com/dynamic/products/sql-development/sql-search/download